# Webpack alias and dependencies/sub-dependencies

Tags: typescript, webpack, dependencies, alias

I've read the documentation for Webpack's [alias](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias) functionality and also researched on StackOverflow and elsewhere, but I was hoping for some clarification.

Suppose in my *package.json* I have the following 'dependencies':

- 'package-a' (which depends on 'package-x').
- 'package-b' (which depends on 'package-c', which in turn depends on 'package-x').
- 'alias-package-x'.

If I add the following to my webpack.config.js:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    'package-x$': 'alias-package-x'
  }
}
```

does Webpack alias 'package-x' for all dependencies, and their dependencies, etc.?  So for example if some function in 'package-c' imports a class from 'package-x', would it now import that class from 'alias-package-x' instead?  Does the alias in my project extend through all the dependencies of my package dependencies?

Thanks for the clarification!